# Should I use Java or Logstash to index db content in Elastic Search?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm building a simple web application that will list/search retail items for sale.

design is like this ...

MySQL database -> Elastic Search deployment -> Spring Boot REST service -> Web UI (JSP/Bootstrap or Angular)

I am planning to write Java client code to read the database and post records to Elastic Search for indexing.

Googling, it looks like Logstash is used for this sort of thing.  I'm not familiar with Logstash, I am very familiar with Java.

QUESTION: Is Java client considered a "deprecated" or "legacy" way to submit data to Elastic Search for indexing?

I'm very familiar with Java, should I use Java or Logstash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding to @chris answer, logstash will add complexity and another Infrastructure to maintain in your stack, and logstash is known for getting stuck and is not as resilient as Elasticsearch is.

You are already using Java for your application code and btw elasticsearch now officially has a java client known as [java high-level rest client(JHLRC)](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/master/java-rest-high.html) , which is very popular and provides an exhaustive list of APIs for indexing/searching and building a modern search system.
IMHO you should use the JHLRC,

1. which will save you to the pain points of logstash
2. you don't have to learn another tool
3. simple infrastructure
4. simple deployment
5. last but not least simple and easy to maintain codebase.

Answer (score 1):

Logstash is good tool to be used to migrate the data from many sources to elastic search. It's build in java language only.

You can use Logstash. It also has options to mutate the data or filter the data. Its a ready to use to tool which will save lot of your development time and efforts.

But if you have a requirement for lot of customisation and need lot of control over your data before pushing it to elastic search then you can build your own application for the same.

Coming back to your question..java is not deprecated for indexing data to elastic search. It is still a preferred option.